# How to see logs in browserstack?

Tags: react-native, expo, browserstack

I have developed a React Native App using Expo. It is working as expected in Android as well as my local iOS simulator. However, when i upload the ipa file to browserstack and test in the iOS devices available there, the app crashes as soon as it opens. I am unable to see any logs on why the app crashed.

I have found this api to see the logs from [here](https://www.browserstack.com/docs/app-automate/appium/debug-failed-tests/appium-logs):

```
curl -u "reactnativeexpo:D4FeD2vwgybBEqbUxAXp" -X GET "https://api-cloud.browserstack.com/app-automate/builds/<build-id>/sessions/<session-id>/appiumlogs"
```

But I can't find out what `build-id` and `session-id` are to use this api. Is this the correct way to see the logs? And if so, what are `build-id` and `session-id`?

Answer (score 1):

You can directly view the logs from the Dashboard and the session id is present on the UI itself

Also, regarding the ios app might be an entitlement issue On App Automate only support the Keychain access entitlement. All other entitlements are removed during the re-signing process.

Apart from this, BrowserStack only supports the following export methods for an IPA file which is to be tested on our infrastructure:

- Ad Hoc
- Enterprise
- Development

OR

You need to sign your application with an Enterprise certificate and use the "browserstack.resignapp" = false capability. This will bypass resigning process and the entitlements will remain intact.

You can read more about it here.
https://www.browserstack.com/question/778